# how to sync a folder with drive using google drive android api? What is Transparent offline Sync?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to sync a folder with google drive. where it should check for local mobile sdcard folder files if they are not present in google drive it should upload such files to drive and vice versa based on time and date.

And in New Google Drive Android Api What is Transparent offline Sync ? any example code on that.

Answer (score 2):

"Transparent offline sync" is referring to the fact that items that already exist in the user's drive may be available offline, and that if you create or modify files while offline, the changes will be sent up to the folder when they come online.

There isn't any code involved, it just happens in the background as you use the API.

Comment: Thank you Cheryl Simon. Do you have any idea about how to sync a folder to drive as i mentioned in the question. I mean any logic to do it.

Comment: There is no logic involved, you create a folder (or create/update file, with content) and you will see it in the Drive (using the web browser, for instance). As long as you are connected, of course. There are 3 pieces of demo code available on Github,  https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos, https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart, https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA, all fully functional. You'll have to build your test suite using them and most of your questions will be answered by stepping through the code.

Comment: seanpj Thank you so much its really helpful to me.

Comment: How can the app know when a specific content/metadata change has been synced?

Comment: did you solved your problem syncing the folder? can you share?

Answer (score 2):

No way to do a bi-directionnal synchronisation of a directory with google drive on android even using a simple call to the google drive API. You will have to use the timestamps of the file/directories AND to handle the deletion/creation, you will have to keep a trace of all the timestamps of all your file tree at a given time... If anyone could say I am wrong and explain me another way using the API (better) or configuring google drive (as you can do on a PC) I would be gratefull. Another idea is to use a clever android app such as FolderSync.